# How to pass and receive an http request body in GET?

Tags: 8, http-request

I have two Drupal sites within one project.

I want to send a GET request but I need to pass a lot of parameters. So instead of passing them in the query (which will lead to an extremely long URL), I want to include them in the request's body.

I know that using POST is preferable in this case but I cannot change this due to the specification of the project.

So my question is how exactly can this be done?

I am using a code like this on the sending side:

```
$options['query']['parameters'] = 'my parameters';
$options['body'] = 'the body';
\GuzzleHttp\Client::request('GET', $uri, $options);
```

On the receiving side I use this code:

```
$parameters = \Drupal::request()->get('parameters');
```

So how can I catch `$options['body']` on the receiving side too?

Comment: This is technically impossible, HTTP GET does not work this way, it has no body by spec.

Comment: Some systems see a GET request with a body as a hacking attempt. This is not normal and cannot be advised.

Comment: OK, I see. Well, it seems that I need to implement POST in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is allowed by spec, see the comment from @Hudri and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body, but it works.

When adding a body in a Guzzle GET request it ends up in a Drupal controller:

```
public function build(Request $request) {
  $body = $request->getContent();
  return ['#markup' => $body];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the body content using Request->getContent() method.

Next I leave a full running example:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\test_api\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

/**
 * Launches the given game
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "test_sample",
 *   label = @Translation("Test Sample"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/test/api/v1/sample"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class GameLaunchResource extends ResourceBase {

  /**
   *  A curent user instance.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  /**
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
   */
  protected $currentRequest;

  /**
   * Constructs a Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase object.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param array $serializer_formats
   *   The available serialization formats.
   * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
   *   A logger instance.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface $current_user
   *   The current user instance.
   * @param Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $current_request
   *   The current request
   */
  public function __construct(
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    array $serializer_formats,
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    AccountProxyInterface $current_user,
    Request $current_request
  ) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $serializer_formats, $logger);
    $this->currentUser = $current_user;
    $this->currentRequest = $current_request;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->getParameter('serializer.formats'),
      $container->get('logger.factory')->get('sample_api'),
      $container->get('current_user'),
      $container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()
    );
  }

  /**
   * Responds to entity GET requests.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function get() {
    $json = '';
    $content = $this->currentRequest->getContent();
    if (!empty($content)) {
      $json = json_decode($content);
    }

    return new ResourceResponse($json);
  }
}
```

About general specifications for GET, there is no specification for the BODY. So you can use it or not, accordingly to your needs. For example, when I have to retrieve a collection filtered by complex conditions I usually send all the conditions in the body, as the URI doesn't have room enough for all the data I need to send.

About specific specifications for GET in Drupal, it's not considered by default, but as I showed in previous example, you can get it through the Request object.